# WPF DataGrid filtering for Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, datagrid, filtering, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF application using Caliburn.Micro. A DataGrid is bound to a collection of objects in the ViewModel. Could you please suggest a way to filter the DataGrid contents, if possible by any field?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you binding to collection (List, ObservableCollection) or CollectionView? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a new property in the view-model:

```
private ICollectionView fooView;

public ICollectionView FooView
{
    get
    {
        return this.fooView;
    }

    set
    {
        this.fooView = value;

        NotifyPropertyChanged("FooView");
    }
}
```

And then after you populate the bindable collection:

```
// Populate collection
BindableCollection collectionName = this.PopulateCollection();

FooView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collectionName);
```

In your view change the binding from `collectionName` to `FooView`.

The CollectionView classes provide ways to sort/filter/group the data. In your case [How to: Filter Data in a View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752348.aspx). The filter code will vary depending on your model and requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a problem with this though. As I understand, this method lets me do filtering like "Show only unfilled orders" or "Show all orders" etc., but I need to be able to let the user pick e.g. a Customer when he wants to filter by customer, and display all records where Customer is the Customer selected by the user. We cannot use logic like in the provided example (e.g. return (order.Filled == "No");), because Customer is not a fixed list of values like "Yes" or "No".

Comment: You can create multiple filter event handlers (for any field you want to apply filter against). So when the user selected a value of type Customer, apply the handler for field of type Customer (`+= new FilterEventHandler(ShowRecordsByCustomer);` for example). If he selects a value of type Orders, apply the filter for that type of field.

Comment: Hello. Do you have found the way to do it. I could be interested by a sample of code